# c++: Identifier T is undefined

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

I tried creating a template with an argument called `T`.

But, the problem is that the compiler said that the identifier is undefined when I'm trying to use it.

I tried doing this (`len.hpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
unsigned int len(T item[]){
    unsigned int res = 0;
    try{
        for (unsigned int i = 0; true; i++){
            item[i];
            res = i;
        }
    }
    catch(...){}
    return res + 1;
}

unsigned int len(std::string str){
    return str.length();
}

unsigned int len(std::vector<T> vec){
    return len(vec.data());
}
```

Comment: You understand that `template<typename T>` only affects the single function after it? Yet you're using `T` in the last overload as well, without writing `template<typename T>` before it.

Comment: There are no exceptions for out of bound access, you loop is wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks! I originally saw this template tutorial at the Cherno, Without thinking it was only for before the function,

Comment: @Jarod42, Then how do I get the length?

Comment: @AdamGewely one way to get the length of a c-style array would be to make the parameter a reference and let the compiler deduce the correct size, e.g. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bxrqbhcEE)

Answer (score 2):

Your `template` is applied only to the 1st overload of `len()`, but you are trying to use the template's `T` argument in the 3rd overload as well.  So, you need to add another `template` to the 3rd overload, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
unsigned int len(T item[]) {
    ...
}

// no template is needed here, unless you want this
// function to handle std::(w|u16|u32)string as well...
unsigned int len(std::string str) {
    ...
}

template<typename T>
unsigned int len(std::vector<T> vec) {
    ...
}
```

That being said...

- your 1st overload is flawed as it is running an endless loop.
- the 2nd and 3rd overloads are taking in their input parameters *by value*, which means they are going to make *copies* of any data passed to them.  To avoid that, they should take in their parameters *by (const) reference* instead, eg:

  ```cpp
  unsigned int len(const std::string &str) {
      ...
  }

  template<typename T>
  unsigned int len(const std::vector<T> &vec) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- the 3rd overload can simply return `vec.size()` instead of calling the 1st overload at all, eg:

  ```cpp
  template<typename T>
  unsigned int len(const std::vector<T> &vec) {
      return vec.size();
  }
  ```
- the standard C++ library already has overloaded [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) functions that handle C arrays and standard containers.  So, your `len()` functions are basically redundant.